How to fetch data from a google drive link using Javascript?
I have been trying to fetch the data from google drive link but facing network issue. Error: Error fetching data: AxiosError {message: "Network Error", name: "AxiosError", code: "ERR_NETWORK", config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest}

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1U9kbPoIturvwKNk0ZPGACirROId6j2or');
        console.log(response)
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);


What is the specific error? Normally your code cause an error about cors because is not possible fetch data crisis domain. Is it your case?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
